# Are there any tutorials on how to create jpeg images or convert images into jpeg on Android?

Tags: android

1.myJpegFile = new File("images/jpegImage.jpg");
 2.output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myJpegFile));
 3.encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(output);
 4.encoder.encode(myJpegImage);

Please could you give me the equivalent code for line no. 3 and 4 in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);