# Convert an android acreen as Jpeg image

Tags: android

Hi everyone
I am creating a greeting card application wherein the user can choose from a set of backgrounds and add text to it.Now my question is how can I convert this screen as a JPEG image which can be sent as a mail to someone.That is the entire greeting card (image+text) is a jpeg image for the viewer.

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content) will help you. In order to capture the screen as an image buffer you will need root privileges - this isn't appropriate for applications in the Market.

If you are using a Canvas to draw the screen, you could get a bitmap out of it and convert it to  a jpg file. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099051/are-there-any-tutorials-on-how-to-create-jpeg-images-or-convert-images-into-jpeg) for details.